# Got AlreadyHasActiveConnectionError error while trying to run migration in Typeorm

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I got this error while trying to run Typeorm migration:
*AlreadyHasActiveConnectionError: Cannot create a new connection named "default", because connection with such name already exist and it now has an active connection session.*
It works on one machine, but doesn't work on another and on Heroku. Maybe there is a specific command to kill all existing connections?
keepConnectionAlive didn't help.
Here is my ormconfig file:

```
module.exports = {
type: "postgres",
host: process.env.DB_HOST,
port: +process.env.DB_PORT,
username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
entities: ["dist/**/*.entity.js"],
synchronize: true,
autoLoadEntities: true,
migrations: ["dist/migration/**/*.js"],
cli: {
  migrationsDir: "src/migration",
},
ssl: process.env.DB_ENV === 'development' ? false : {
  rejectUnauthorized: false
}
```

};

Comment: We need more information. Sounds like you have multiple conenctions without custom names?! How are your connections configured/included in the app module?

Comment: @marcel, there was some running nodejs processes. I killed them and now everything is fine.